# SCCM deployment removed but application still getting deployed

Tags: sccm

An action was taken last month to delete deployments from an Application that was made available as required install earlier last month. There are no longer any deployments associated with the package but some users have reported that they just got the application installed on their computer from the same package.

Not sure why would that be as there are no associated deployments with the package anymore. The original application package was pushed out to user collection.

Any help identifying potential causes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Comment: The most porbable cause would be that another application has a dependency on the first one.

Comment: potentially supercedence?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the [Configuration Manager Support Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/support/support-center) on a model device, then search the [Content tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/support/support-center-ui-reference#bkmk_support-content) for the application.

If it does appear there, it might indicate a problem with policy update. Check the PolicyAgent.log and PolicyAgentProvider.log for possible errors.

It may also be because of dependency / supersedence, check the [references tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/apps/deploy-use/revise-and-supersede-applications#to-display-applications-that-supersede-the-current-application) in the application's Properties.

If it does not appear you can check the AppEnforce.log to verify that the application installation was performed by the SCCM Agent, and at what time.